# Why no Integer output

Tags: java, netbeans

Does anyone know why I'm not getting the actual integers for out put... I get WorkOut@1261281792. I know it is something small but can't figure it out. here are my 3 classes:

```
public class WorkOut1 {

    public static void main(String [] args) {      

        Exercise tuesWorkout = new Exercise (10, 50);

        PullUps tuesPullUps = new PullUps (10, 50);

        System.out.println("This Tuesday our workout will consist of this many minutes and reps:");
        System.out.println(tuesWorkout);
    }
}
```

**PullUps Class**

```
public class PullUps extends Exercise {

    private static int barHeight;

    public PullUps (int min, int reps) {
        super(min, reps);
        barHeight = 6;
    }
}
```

**Exercise class**

```
public class Exercise {

    private static int min;
    private static int reps;

    //Constructor
    public Exercise(int min,int reps) {
        this.min = min;
        this.reps = reps;
    }// end constructor

    public static int howManyMin() {
        return min;
    }//end method howmanyMin()

     public static int howManyReps() {
        return reps;
    }//end method howmanyReps()

}//end class
```

Comment: That is what you are supposed to get.

You are asking to "print" out the actual instance of the Workout1 class.

Which is what you get.

Comment: If you want to print out, for example, reps, you want to do something along the lines of `System.out.println(tuesWorkout.howManyReps())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call an object to be printed, the object's toString() method is called, which in this case it will inherit from the Object class (this is a Java class from which all classes inherit from) since you haven't defined a toString() method in the Exercise class. So you are getting the Object name + a hash representation of the object. One fix will be to create a toString method in the object to be printed (in this case Exercise) that returns a string of what you want printed.

```
public String toString() {
    return(min + ", " + reps);
}
```

The other option is to print the result of the accessor function for the property you want printed in your main class.

```
System.out.println(tuesWorkout.howManyMin() + ", " + tuesWorkout.howManyReps());
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian... this is a great help.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to print the actual `tuesWorkout` object itself.

You want to to do:

`System.out.println(tuesWorkout.howManyReps());`

Which gives you the number of reps.

Then you have to call your `getter` for `min` to find out how many `min` the workout is.

By just calling `System.out.println(tuesWorkout)` it is like printing the actual Object itself, which has no real meaning to us.

Comment: Additionally, if the goal is to be able to print a custom format for your classes you may want to look into overriding their `public String toString()` method.

Comment: Ahh yes.

An even better idea.